# Calculate number of rows as a column in a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Sorry about the title, it's hard to summarize what I am asking for.

Given this:

`SELECT [FirstName], [LastName], '-', [Thing] FROM.....`

```
John Smith - Plow
James Jones - Plow
James Jones - Shovel
James Jones - Axe
Sarah Lee - Hammer
Sarah Lee - Pliers
```

I need to get this:

```
John Smith - Plow - 1
James Jones - Plow - 3
James Jones - Shovel - 3
James Jones - Axe - 3
Sarah Lee - Hammer - 2
Sarah Lee - Pliers - 2
```

I need to include as a column the sum number of times that same person has appeared in the rows.

This is sounding like a pivot solution, but pivots make my brain hurt.  Is there another way?  if not, can anyone explain the pivot, if that's what it has to come to?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT  *,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY FirstName, LastName) cnt
FROM    mytable
```

Comment: No problem.I was doing the fiddle before the adding the answer and saw you had answered it. Feel free to add it to your answer (no attribution required)

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most efficient way to write it but gets the job done.

```
select
firstname
,Surname
,count(firstname + Surname) over (partition by firstname + surname) as NameOccurences
from table
```

Comment: Careful there. Partitioning by `firstname`/`surname` is not the same thing. "alpha" + "beta" = "alph" + "abeta", a match that would not be made if you keep the fields separate. And don't try adding a space when there is a simple, correct way to handle it.

Comment: @HABO, could you clarify that for me?  I'm not following.

"alpha" + "beta" would not equal "alpha" + "abeta".  I do not understand what you mean by "keeping the fields seperate", or what you mean by "adding a space".

Serious question.  Not being coy.

Comment: You have `(partition by firstname + surname)`. That will treat the first name/surname pairs "alpha"/"beta" and "alph"/"abeta" as identical because they both become "alphabeta". Using `(partition by firstname, surname)` will treat them as distinct because it is checking two separate fields. A hack would be to add a blank: `(partition by firstname + ' ' + surname)`. While that might work in this case, I've seen too many cases of people trying to compare rows by just concatenating all of the columns without realizing what can go wrong. I'm happy to explain. Not being coy.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a way on my own.  I like the "OVER/Partition by" solutions though.  Much shorter, but not as obvious to me what they are doing.

Here's what I eventually came up with:

```
with cte as (
    select last_name, first_name, count(1) as theCount
    from MetalThings
    group by last_name, first_name
)
select  m.*,
        cte.theCount
from    MetalThings m
    JOIN cte on (m.last_name = cte.last_name and m.first_name = cte.first_name)
```